# Squeeze words broken by spaces without affecting other words in the sentence

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have got a sentence like that:

```
The fox j u m p e d over the big b r o w n boar !
```

I want to change this into:

```
The fox jumped over the big brown boar !
```

**(Note - spaces squashed when in middle, but left between full words and exclamation mark)**

I wrote this code to do so:

```
str = 'The fox j u m p e d over the big b r o w n boar !'
prev_char = '0'
prev_prev_char = '0'
next_next_char = '0'
new_str = ''
(0..(str.length)).each do |index|
  t_char = str[index]
  prev_char = index > 0 ? str[index-1] : '0'
  prev_prev_char = index > 1 ? str[index-2] : '0'
  next_next_char = index-1 < str.length ? str[index+2] : '0'
  new_str = "#{new_str}#{t_char}" unless t_char == ' ' && prev_char != ' ' && prev_prev_char == ' ' && next_next_char == ' '
end
results = new_str.split(' ').join(' ')
p (results == 'The fox jumped over the big brown boar !')
```

But I'm sure there is a better or more clever approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is expected from `A fox j u m p e d...`?

Comment: @M42 I'll expect it to be 'A fox jumped...'

Comment: Then what's the rule to aggregate letters? Why `a f o x` becomes `a fox` and not `afox`?

Comment: Well. I'd say the rule is case of more than one space. So I'd expect a failure for 'A G F o x jumped' ==> 'A GFox jumped' but that's fine.

Comment: Re: A Fox Jumped... There are only 'two' one letter words. "I,A" There has to be an exclusion for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a short one:

```
(?:(?<=\s\w)|(?<=^\w))\s(?=\w\W)
```

Replace matches with the empty string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cB2uL9/3).

It's based on the assumption that there'll never be two single-character words right next to each other. If it finds such a thing, it'll remove the space inbetween.

If you want to get fancy, you can prevent it from picking up `I a`, as in `Am I a good programmer?`, and from concatenating lower- and upper case characters:

```
(?:(?<=\s\w)|(?<=^\w))\s+(?=[a-z]\W)(?!(?<=I\s)a)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cB2uL9/6).

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=\s[a-zA-Z])\s(?=[a-zA-Z]\s[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z](?:$|\.))
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gQ3kS4/15

Comment: Sorry for always being picky, but this doesn't work if the second character is a space, e.g. `T h e` -> `T he`.

Comment: @vks You're definitely doing well... But you need an exclusion for, "I and A"... the only one-letter words in English. (?![ia])